# `grep` in Mac doesn't return results with dollar sign using RegEx

Tags: regex, macos, terminal

I am currently learning RegEx on my Mac, and am facing an issue which I haven't been able to find a straight forward resolution to online.

the following RegEx cmd:

```
grep -E '^[a-z]{4,6}$' regex.txt
```

The dollar sign ($) isn't limiting my results to 6 characters, and I receive no results instead, as seen in the image below. Any suggestion to resolve would be appreciated.

Expected result: Interested in returning all words between 4 and 6 characters.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Make sure the file doesn't have Windows CRLF line breaks.

Comment: Also check for spaces at the end of the lines.

Comment: Use `tr -d '\r' < regex19.txt > regex19fixed.txt` to remove CR characters.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the responses +1. The solution you provided above resolved the issue.